# How do I reference XML data that's not in quotes?

Tags: xml

I am very new to this whole XML stuff. Sorry if my terminology is incorrect. I am trying to reference The following data from the provided code.

210 from "Calories"

35 from "Calories from Fat"

3.5 g from "Total Fat"

0.5 g from "Saturated Fat"

I found how to access the data that's in quotes, but I don't know what script will grab the information between the > <

```
<Nutrients>
  <Nutrient name="Calories" UOM="kcal" 
            allowanceRate="" 
            allowanceStandard="N/A" 
            unroundedValue="214.8893805500001">210</Nutrient>

  <Nutrient name="Calories from Fat" UOM="kcal" 
            allowanceRate="" 
            allowanceStandard="N/A" 
            unroundedValue="33.2709996060006">35</Nutrient>

  <Nutrient name="Total Fat" UOM="g" 
            allowanceRate="6%" 
            allowanceStandard="DV" 
            unroundedValue="3.6967777340001">3.5 g</Nutrient>

  <Nutrient name="Saturated Fat" UOM="g" 
            allowanceRate="3%" 
            allowanceStandard="DV" 
            unroundedValue="0.6293593995000">0.5 g</Nutrient>
</Nutrients>
```

Comment: what language / what method are you using to read the XML?

Comment: Are you writing in a scripting language? Which one?

Comment: How are you trying to access it? VB.Net, C#, Java? We're not [mind readers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172661) - if you don't tell us what you're talking about, it's very difficult to give you an answer. (And just to clarify: XML is not "code", it's "data" - that might help with terminology some.) :-)

Comment: Time for you to learn some XML terms.

Comment: I have very very little knowledge of XML. Sorry for not being clear. I was told the system I'm using to retrieve the data is E4x AS3.

Comment: I would love to learn some XML terms. Anyone know where I can view a dictionary of XML terms?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever programming environment you are using, there's a good chance it allows you to retrieve data using XPath. With XPath, the following expression will get what you want:

```
string(/Nutrients/Nutrient[@name=$name])
```

where $name is a parameter supplied from your calling API. Some APIs do not allow you to set parameters, in which case you will need to construct the expression by string concatenation, for example

```
string(/Nutrients/Nutrient[@name='Calories'])
```

(be careful if you do it this way to guard against the risk of code injection, which applies to XPath just as it does to SQL).

Comment: I'm using E4x AS3. Does that help?

Comment: It might help someone, but not me: it's not an environment I'm familiar with.